# Install tube sealant, Schrader?

Tags: innertube, beginner, sealant, schrader

I have normal tube sealant that I want to install in my bicycle's tubes.

My bicycle's tubes have Schrader valves.

Will someone here please provide total-noob friendly instructions on how to do what I want to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To install the sealant you will need to remove the valve core. Insert the tool into the valve and unscrew the core.  Your sealant container may include one built into the cap of the container. My SLIME container came with one. You can purchase a valve core tool for a few dollars at an auto parts supplier or Harbor Freight. Deflate the tire, remove the core.  Follow the sealant manufacturers instruction in regards to amount of sealant, reinstall the core. Inflate the tire per the sealant makers direction.

Comment: As suggested the automotive variety vavle core tool works just fine. No need to by a blue bicycle specific valve core tool that costs 10x more.

Comment: In my experience with slime and Schrader Valves your better off getting a better quality tire that can withstand most resistance to punctures. All slime does is eventually clog up the valve rendering it useless and you need a new tube anyway. Slime also won't stop a 2" gash from your tire so it's a new tube again. At most slime will protect from pin hole punctures but so will a decent tire.

Comment: @Dan K "All slime does is eventually clog up the valve" does that mean that in your opinion from your experience, if I install my slime then I will soon be unable to pump my tubes??

Comment: @Cycle_Heath sometimes you can remove the valve core and clean them and refit the core, not ideal if your in the sticks though and don't have a valve core remover. I used to use slime a lot but everytime I had issues with the valve clogging up. In the long run it's just easier to replace the tube if you get a puncture

Comment: just to make it clear I was not advocating the use of slime in a bike tube. (It worked great in my wheelbarrow tire). I was just stating that some sealant comes with a core removal tool.